# Invalid Syntax because of commas

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to do a program that counts vowels, consonants and other chars. The problem is in the returning because of commas and I can't understand why. It is supposed to return, for example, "2 vowels, 3 consonants and 5 others".
This is my program (sorry for any english mistakes):

```
    def count1(word):
        vowels = 0
        consonants = 0
        others = 0

        l1 = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

        for i in range(len(word)):
           if word[i] in l1:
              vowels = vowels + 1

           elif (word[i] >= 'a' and word[i] <= 'z') or (word[i] >= 
            'A' and word[i] <= 'Z'):
              consonants = consonants + 1

           else :
            others = others+ 1
        return(vowels "vowels," consonants "consonants," outros "others")
```

Comment: Many typos here. Try `return vowels, "vowels", consonants, "consonants", others, "others"`.

Comment: @jpp I've tried that, but it appears "2 "vowels", 3 "consonantes", 3 "others" " instead of "2 vowels, 3 consonantes, 3 others"

Answer (score 2):

You should format the string before you return it:

```
return '{} vowels, {} consonants, {} others'.format(vowels, consonants, others)
```

Or using f-string in Python 3.6+

```
return f'{vowels} vowels, {consonants} consonants, {others} others'
```

Comment: I tried with %d, but it wasn't working either, but with your notation it really works. What's the main difference?